# WebService with ComplexData type as input

Tags: java, web-services, input, annotations, java-web-start

I have the question why when I use the Java Annotation (import javax.jws.*) for WebServices, I don't get an complex java class members with the correct value?

f.e:

[1.] With simple type as service input

```
import javax.jws.WebMethod;

@WebService
public class WebServiceClass{

    @WebMethod
    public void webMethodSample(int inValue){
        int i = inValue;

    }
}
```

Result: That works fine.

[2.] With Java Class/Object (Complex type) as service input:

```
import javax.jws.WebMethod;

@WebService
public class WebServiceClass{

    @WebMethod
    public void webMethodSample(SimpleObj inObj){
        int i = inObj.getValue();

    }
}
```

-> SimpleObj:

```
public class SimpleObj {
    private int m_Value = 0;

    public void setValue(int inValue){
        this.m_Value = inValue;
    }
    public int getValue(){
        return this.m_Value;            
    }
}
```

Result: The variable 'i' which comes from the "SimpleObj" inputObject is not the value which I pass from an SOAP Client Program.

Can anybody helps me what I do wrong?

Thanks and Greets

Tommy

Answer (score 0):

What isnt `this.Value` in your getter/setter?

Comment: Ah that's of course in the getter and setter the member variable 'm_Value'!

Comment: One thing which strikes me, that any Object you transfer that way has to be Serializable, but I don't know if that's all.

Besides that, you might have to provide your Client to tell more. Did you generate the portable artefacts for the webservice client (e.g. via wsimport or a framework like axis)?

Comment: Yes, I did it with axis and this simpe object should be serializable.

Comment: The Client I tested with WebServiceExplorer in Eclipse and I generated all over the wsdl.

Comment: Well, as I said, it may not be the source of the problem - but still, your class is not serializable, even though it has only an Integer, which itself is serializable. I cite from the Javadoc: "Serializability of a class is enabled by the class implementing the java.io.Serializable interface. Classes that do not implement this interface will not have any of their state serialized or deserialized"

Comment: But the strange thing is when I make the int value public it works!? Has anybody there about an idea?